# Unable to reach ' if ' condition within Spinner onItemSelected() in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I create customized spinner for my application. I can get the selected spinner item and i can display it too. But I'm not able to reach my if condition within my spinner's onItemSelected() . I wasn't able to check my conditions within spinner. Where did I make a mistake ? can anybody tell me? And how can i resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post and format code in here. Read the FAQ

Comment: You said it's a spinner but on your code it's extend an activity ???

Comment: your code cannot compile as `cash_month_select.setOnItemSelectedListener(CashFlow .this);` CashFlow.this is not an OnItemSelectedListener

Comment: why do you compare the value of month[position] rather than position itself ?

Comment: @njzk2 can you tell me how??

Comment: @jaumard Please check it now!!!

Comment: for instance, you are testing if month[position] is 'january', which is like testing if month[position] is month[0]. Isn't it easier to test if position is 0 ? (same apply (obviously) to all 12 months)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try like this . The if condition will works within spinner onItemSelected() .
http://pastie.org/5452818

```
   @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id)
{

  spinner_value =  parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
  Log.i("spinner_value", ".."+spinner_value);

       if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("January"))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {

    }
```

Just compare with parent.getItemAtPosition(position) it will works..... Thank you.